# Line 51: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float what is wrong plz help me

Tags: python, python-3.x

The Line   .  . .. if self.collide(state.platform_list[plat_index]):  is giving me an error FLOAT and IDK how to fix it

```
def update (self, state):
    global timer
    timer+1
    self.pos[0] = (self.pos[0] + self.vel[0]) % CANVAS_WIDTH
    plat_index = min(self.pos[1] // PLATFORM_SPACING, NUM_PLAT - 1)
    if self.collide(state.platform_list[plat_index]):           
        BOUNCE_SOUND.play()
        self.vel[1] = max(-self.vel[1], REBOUND_VELOCITY)
        if random.random()> .678:   
            state.platform_list[plat_index].remove()
    else:
        self.pos[1] += self.vel[1]
        self.vel[1] -= .1
        if self.pos[1] - state.camera_pos[1] > CANVAS_HEIGHT - CLEARANCE:
            state.camera_pos[1] = self.pos[1] - (CANVAS_HEIGHT - CLEARANCE)
        if self.pos[1] - state.camera_pos[1] < -50:
            finish_time = time.time()
            state.start_game()
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line is giving you the error because `plat_index` is actually a float. Assuming your capitalized constants are integers, `self.pos[1]` must be a float. You'll have to look farther back in your code to see how that number was generated. As a short-term workaround, just use [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
plat_index = min(int(self.pos[1]) // PLATFORM_SPACING, NUM_PLAT - 1)
```

Or, you could call `int()` on the whole thing, just to be sure:

```
plat_index = int(min(self.pos[1] // PLATFORM_SPACING, NUM_PLAT - 1))
```

Also, as a side note, the line `timer+1` doesn't actually do anything, because it doesn't store the resulting value anywhere.

Comment: the timer+1 is for a stopwatch im adding in the game itself so you can see how long you last in the game but thank you

Comment: @HENRYMANnnnsfrg my point is that just having `timer+1` on a line doesn't change `timer`, because you haven't assigned the new value to it. You probably want `timer += 1` instead.